# stop UIImageView.transition

Tags: swift, animation

i have animation that starts after view appeares and i need to stop it by tap, but animation doesnt stop

code:

Property

```
private var isAnimating = true
```

Animation (every 0.1 seconds shows new image)

```
func animateImage() {
        UIImageView.transition(with: self.imageView, duration: 0.1, options: .transitionCrossDissolve) {
            self.imageView.setImage(imageUrl: self.imagesArray[self.nextImage])
        } completion: { _ [weak self] in
            if self.nextImage != self.imagesCount - 1 {
                self.nextImage += 1
            } else {
                self.nextImage = 0
            }
            self.animateImage()
        }
    }
```

UITapGestureRecognizer

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapOnImage))
self.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Action for tap

```
@objc func tapOnImage(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if isAnimating {
            imageView.stopAnimating()
        } else {
            imageView.startAnimating()
        }
        isAnimating.toggle()
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the completion handler, you call `self.animateImage()` again to form a loop. If you call this *conditionally* on `isAnimating`, then the loop will "break" once `isAnimating` is false:

```
completion: { _ [weak self] in
    guard let `self` = self else { return }
    if self.nextImage != self.imagesCount - 1 {
        self.nextImage += 1
    } else {
        self.nextImage = 0
    }
    // notice this condition
    if self.isAnimating { 
        self.animateImage() 
    }
}
```

Also note that `imageView.startAnimating()` starts animating using the `imageView.animationImages`, not the animation you have created here with `UIImageView.animate`, which is just the same as `UIView.animate`. So you only need the single line of

```
isAnimating.toggle()
```

in `tapOnImage`.

Since you seem to want to restart the animation when `isAnimating` is set to true, you should call `animateImage` in its `didSet`:

```
private var isAnimating = true {
    didSet {
        if isAnimating {
            animateImage()
        }
    }
}
```